# Flask/Javascript - Post image to server then get image to read as data URL

Tags: javascript, python, ajax, sqlite, flask

I'm making a blogging app with image functionality. You don't have to upload all the images at once. Images may be input anywhere from one to whatever at a time. As you upload the images, you are given a preview of the images you'll be uploading before you hit submit. After you hit submit, files are saved to disk, and the paths to them are joined into a string which is then saved to the SQLite database.

What I want now is the ability to edit the images attached to a post, and to preview the images already uploaded and the ones added to the post while editing.

Here's a simplified mockup of what I have now:

index.html

```
<script src='https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js'></script>
<a href='{{ url_for("blog.create") }}'>Create New Post</a>
{% for post in posts %}
  <article>
    <a href='{{ url_for('blog.edit', id=post['id']) }}'>Edit</a>
    {% for images in post['images'].split(post['separator']) %}
      <img src='{{ url_for('static', filename=image) }}'>
    {% endfor %}
  </article>
{% endfor %}
<script src='{{ url_for("static", filename='script.js') }}'></script>
```

create.html

```
<form method='post' enctype='multipart/form-data'>
  <div class='gallery'></div>
  <input type='file' name='file[]' accept='image/*' onchange='previewFiles()' multiple>
  <input type='submit' value='Submit'>
</form>
```

script.js

```
var queue = []

function previewFiles() {
  var files = document.querySelector('input[type=file]').files

  function readAndPreview(file){
    if (/\.(jpe?g|png|gif)$/i.test(file.name)){
      var reader = new FileReader()
      reader.addEventListener('load', function(){
        queue.push(file)
        image = document.createElement('img')
        image.src = this.result
        document.querySelector('div.gallery').appendChild(image)
      }, false)
      
      reader.readAsDataURL(file)
    }
  }


  if(files){
    [].forEach.call(files, readAndPreview)
  }
}

var form = document.querySelector('form')

$(form).submit(function(event){
  var formData = new FormData(this)
  formData.append('file[]', queue)

  $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: '/',
    data: formData
  })

  event.preventDefault()
})
```

blog.py

```
import os, string, random
from flask import (
  request, render_template, redirect, url_for, 
)

from . import get_db

def get_random_filename(length, filename):
  letters = string.ascii_letters
  extension = os.path.splitext(filename)[1]
  return ''.join(random.choice(letters) for i in range(length)) + extension

@app.route('/')
def index():
  db = db.execute(
    'SELECT id, images, separator'
    ' FROM post'
    'ORDER BY created DESC'
  ).fetchall()
  return render_template('index.html', posts=posts)

@app.route('/create', methods=('GET', 'POST'))
def create():
  if request.method == 'POST':
    files = request.files.getlist('file[]')
    separator = '&!@%'
    path_to_uploads = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__)), app.static_folder, app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'])
    db = get_db()

    if files:
      file_paths = []
      for file in files:
        filename = get_random_filename(20, file.filename)
        file.save(os.path.join(path_to_uploads, filename))
        file_paths.append(os.path.join(app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'], filename))
      file_list = separator.join(file_paths)
      db.execute(
        'INSERT INTO post (images, separator)'
        ' VALUES (?, ?)',
        (file_list, separator)
      )
      db.commit()
      return redirect(url_for('blog.index'))

  return render_template('create.html')

@app.route('/<int:id>/edit', methods=('GET', 'POST'))
@login_required
def edit(id):
  #???

  return render_template('edit.html', post=post)
```

schema.sql

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS post;

CREATE TABLE post (
  id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
  images TEXT UNIQUE,
  separator TEXT
);
```

Thanks in advance. I'm stuck on this because I haven't found any answers that help with my specific scenario.